# How to make the search parameters in http request as dynamic in jmeter

Tags: rest, http, testing, jmeter, jsr223

http request: http://ipAddress:Port/SomeResource?Param1=value1&Param2=value2&......

so on.
This is a http request sample in jmeter that hits a rest api and gets response in JSON format.

Here the challenge is Param1, param2, param3 .... these search parameters number is not constant it may change depending on the call so i am making a csv file that contains rows that contain search parameters in coma separated format.

```js
CSV file is like
param1,param2
param1,param2,param3
param1
```

I am using a CSV data configure to pull data from the csv file and put it in the http request

[image]

And putting this in http request like

[image]

Now if the param is null i don't want see this in http request header
so how to do this in jmeter.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Remove all "Parameters" from the [HTTP Request](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#HTTP_Request), it should be clean

   [image]
2. Add [JSR223 PreProcessor](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#JSR223_PreProcessor) as a child of the HTTP Request sampler you would like to parameterize
3. Put the following code into "Script" area:

   ```
   1.upto(4, {
       if (vars.get('param' + "$it") != null) {
           sampler.addArgument(vars.get('param' + "$it"),'someValue')
       }
   })
   ```
4. Add [JSR223 PostProcessor](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#JSR223_PostProcessor) as a child of the request you would like to parameterize
5. Put the following code into "Script" area:

   ```
   1.upto(4, {
       vars.remove("param" + "$it")
   })
   ```
6. That's it, you should now get what you need. You will not see the changes in JMeter GUI, you will only be able to observe them in the runtime using [View Results Tree](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/how-debug-your-apache-jmeter-script) listener

   [image]

Comment: Sir can you explain or share some link to understand how this works, because i am unable to understand how this thing works.

Comment: `vars` is a shorthand for [JMeterVariables](https://jmeter.apache.org/api/org/apache/jmeter/threads/JMeterVariables.html) class, it is used for getting `param1`, `param2`, etc. variables values. `sampler` is a shorthand for [HTTPSamplerProxy](https://jmeter.apache.org/api/org/apache/jmeter/protocol/http/sampler/HTTPSamplerProxy.html) class, it's used for adding request parameters. Check out [Top 8 JMeter Java Classes You Should Be Using with Groovy](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/top-8-jmeter-java-classes-you-should-be-using-with-groovy)  for the most commonly used functions.

Comment: Thank you sir for explaining me the way this works and i'm sure this solution works for my problem